# Just installed windows vista dual boot, resolution and drivers problems

Tags: windows, windows-vista, drivers, resolution

I just installed windows vista alongside ubuntu 14.04. The problems are that it both doesn't allow me to set the native resolution of my display (900x1600 or something), it only goes up to 1024x768, as well as it doesn't recognize my broadcomm bc43xx card nor does it recognize ethernet for some reason. I have an acer aspire 7560g with a 240gb intel ssd and 4gb of ram. It ran windows 7 with ease before the original hard drive crashed and I'm wondering why I'm having these issues with vista. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: anyone? don't be shy

Comment: Sounds like you need drivers . . . looks like Vista isn't officially supported, but you could try going to [Acer's website](http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers), and downloading the Win7 drivers . . .

Comment: or I can just find a windows 7 install disk if that will work better, I guess